# xml-layout: ScrollView cuts the bottom of an embedded CardView item

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-cardview

I have a single CardView inside a ScrollView that works flawlessly, as long as the height of the CardView is small enough not to need scrolling. However, if the CardView needs scrolling (in order to display a bigger image), the bottom of the CardView gets cut. What am I doing wrong?

Here's part of my layout.xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_yellow_lighten_4"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_downloaded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- several other TextView elements here not shown -->

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Share your whole layout with question

Comment: I have tested the layout using the code above, omitting other elements. The result (bottom of cardView gets cut) was the same.

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:clipToPadding="false"` and `android:clipChildren="false"` in your `ScrollViewer`

Comment: And also use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for the `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:fillViewPort=true` seems a bit odd. What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: @Sander Just because that's how I usually do, just to test if it works for him.

Comment: @TamHuynh Sorry for the confusion, it wasn't a comment to you but to the OP. Seems like we were typing the same suggestion and you submitted earlier.

Comment: @CEO tech4lifeapps This line seems strange to me: `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`. `ConstraintLayout` is not a scrollable view. @Sander Ok don't worry

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions and options. Unfortunately, the actual result is still the same. What caught my eye, however, is your remark: _ConstraintLayout is not a scrollable view_. So what should I try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I've found:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >
```

1. Remove `android:layout_margin="8dp"` from the CardView
2. Add `app:card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to the CardView

Comment: Glad you can fix it. This solution just reminds me of the situation I've met before but cannot remember at the time. It's silly that the child is clipped by its own margins, but seems reasonable somehow.